# access sublist in c#

Tags: c#, sublist

so i have a List containing a list of strings

```
List<List<string>> NameOfTheList =...
```

what i'm having trouble with at the moment is accessing a sublist and writing its content like:

```
foreach string SAMPLE in ""NameOfTheList.NameOfTheSubList?"" {
    Console.Write(SAMPLE);
}
```

the part with the double "" at the beginning and the end is what doesn't work and i don't understand how to do it. I hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: Are you asking how to get an item from a list? Did you read the documentation?

Comment: Please say what you're trying to do. Do you want to iterate through all the items in all the sublists, or all the items in one sublist, or what?

Comment: lists don't have names, they have indexes so you would need so do variableName[listIndex] to access the sub list

Comment: What do you mean by `NameOfTheSubList`?  Your inner lists don't *have* "names".  They're just lists of strings.  Are you asking how to flatten this entire structure into a single large list of strings?  Something else?

Comment: I want all the contents of 1 sublist but i forgot the sublists can't have names as they are part of the list containing them. I think i got it from here thanks for the fast responses

Comment: It is very unclear for me what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing something like below in order to access the items within your list

```
foreach(var ListItem in NameOfTheList)
{
     foreach(string SubListItem in ListItem)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(SubListItem );
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your goal is to store a set of lists and access each list by a unique name, you should use a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> ListofLists = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
ListofLists.Add("List A", new List<string>()); //add a sublist and  give it a name
List<string> myListA = ListofLists["List A"]; // access the sublist by name
```

You can give each sublist a name and access them by name in this way.

Answer (score 1):

Using LINQ`s [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx) should do the trick:

```
List<List<string>> myList = new List<List<string>>()
{
    new List<string>() { "first", "second" },
    new List<string>() { "third", "fourth" }
    //...
};

foreach (string item in myList.SelectMany(l => l))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

The output will be as expected:

```
first
second
third
fourth
...
```